# Python code running python invoke not executing tasks

Tags: django, pyinvoke

Given the following tasks.py

```
from invoke import run, task

@task
def gems():
    print 'Installing Gems'
    run('echo $PWD')
    #run('export GEM_HOME=$PWD && GEM_PATH=$PWD && gem install sass')

@task('gems')
def setup():
    pass
```

My automation script:

```
import invoke
import invoke.cli

invoke.cli.parse(['-r', os.path.dirname(__file__), '--list'])
```

this returns

```
Available tasks:

  gems
  setup
```

But when try to execute 'gems' as below:

```
invoke.cli.parse(['-r', os.path.dirname(__file__), 'gems'])
```

It is not executing the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `invoke.cli.parse` should use `invoke.cli.dispath` like:

```
invoke.cli.dispatch(['-r', os.path.dirname(__file__), 'setup'])
```